# How to get image from slice image loaded on canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, html, canvas

I have the next code which slice an image. I have the next HTML code

```
<img id="imagen" src="original.png" >
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="150" height="600"></canvas>
```

jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var image = document.getElementById('imagen');
   var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

   image.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 50, image.height, 0, 0, 50, image.height);
   };

   var i = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
   console.log( i );
});
```

Now when I tried to get the sliced part, which is store on the `canvas` variable when I check the `i` I get an black image.
Someone can tell me why this happened and how to solve it? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to draw to the canvas first before you can get the drawing on the canvas as an image, to make sure the canvas is drawn to get the image after the canvas was drawn to

```
image.onload = function() {
   ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 50, image.height, 0, 0, 50, image.height);
   var i = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
   console.log( i );
};
```

Comment: Nice, but I need to use the `i` var outside that function, how can I do that?

Comment: @Jeff: Get rid of the `var` from the `onload` callback. By sticking a `var` behind `i`, you create a *new* `i` that's local only to the callback. Without the `var`, you'd be using the `i` outside of the higher scope.

Comment: @Blender are you telling me something like `var i = image.onload = function....` and inside the function make a `return`? I don't understand the 100% of your answer.

Comment: @Jeff: Sorry, it's a little difficult to explain in words. Just use `i = canvas...` instead of `var i = canvas...`.

Comment: @Blender I made something like this `var i; image.onload = function() {
   ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 50, image.height, 0, 0, 50, image.height);
   i = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');   
}; console.log( i );` but I get `undefined`

Comment: @Jeff: `.onload` is asynchronous. If you want to work with the new value of `i`, you will only be able to do that after `onload` has been called.